# Nomen Verb Verbindungen mit zu

Tags: preposition

1. zum Abschluss bringen
2. zu Wort kommen

Meine Frage ist, warum in der Nummer 2 wird **zu** benutz anstatt **zum** wie Nummer 1?.

Danke im Voraus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wie R. Horber in seiner Antwort schon richtig gesagt hat, ist das Wort *»zum«* eine Kontraktion der beiden Wörter *»zu dem«,* oder aber auch *»zu einem«.* Solche kontraktionen gibt es auch in anderen Sprachen (z.B. englisch: *don't = do not*).

Daher kann man die erste Phrase auch so formulieren:

> **zu** eine**m** Abschluss bringen

Denkbar wäre auch die Variante mit einem bestimmten Artikel:

> **zu** de**m** Abschluss bringen

Damit wird aus der ursprünglichen Frage aber plötzlich eine ganz andere, nämlich:

Warum wird in der Phrase *»zu Wort kommen«* kein Artikel verwendet?

Es gibt nämlich auch die völlig korrekten Varianten mit Artikel:

- bestimmter Artikel

  > Hans und Gerda sehen sich schon zum dritten Mal das Video an, in dem Georg das Wort »Tisch« so seltsam ausspricht. Beide biegen sich schon vor Lachen, und kurz bevor Georg **zu dem Wort kommt** halten beide kurz den Atem an, um danach dann umso lauter loszulachen.
- unbestimmter Artikel

  > Ludwig und Erna spielen Scrabble. Erna ist schon sehr genervt, weil es jedesmal gut und gerne 15 Minuten dauert, bis Ludwig **zu einem Wort kommt.**

Was bedeutet »zu Wort kommen« denn? Diese Phrase bedeutet, dass jemand die Gelegenheit bekommt, etwas zu sagen, und das wiederum bedeutet, Wörter so aneinanderzureihen, dass sie gemeinsam einen Sinn ergeben, und durch diesen verbindenden Sinn werden aus Wörtern Worte. Und während man Wörter sehr leicht zählen kann, ist das bei Worten nicht der Fall, denn Worte sind etwas anderes als Wörter.

Wörter, die Dinge beschrieben, die man nicht zählen kann, werden häufig (aber nicht immer) ohne Artikel verwendet:

> richtig: Das Boot wird zu Wasser gelassen.
> falsch: Das Boot wird zum Wasser gelassen.
> falsch: Das Boot wird zu dem Wasser gelassen.
> falsch: Das Boot wird zu einem Wasser gelassen.
>
> aber: Das Boot wird ins (= in das) Wasser gelassen.

Andere Beispiel:

> richtig: Das Opfer rang um Luft.
> falsch: Das Opfer rang um die/eine Luft.
>
> richtig: Ich wünsche dir Glück.
> falsch: Ich wünsche dir das/ein Glück.

---

Und noch zu einem anderen Beispiel, das in den Kommentaren erwähnt wurde:

> Jürgen kam unerwartet zu Geld.

Hier gilt dasselbe wie bei den Worten: Geld kann man nicht zählen. (Man kann Münzen und Scheine zählen, aber *»ein Geld, zwei Geld, drei Geld usw.« ist unsinnig.)

Mit Geld kann aber auch eine ganz bestimmte Ansammlung von Scheinen und Münzen gemeint sein, und dann braucht man aber einen Artikel:

> A: Ich hab' das Geld, aber die Polizei ist mir auf den Fersen. Aber ich konnte es noch rechtzeitig verstecken. Aber ich kann es nicht selbst aus dem Versteck holen. Das musst du für mich machen.
> B: Ok, verstanden. Sag mir nur wie ich **zu dem Geld komme** und dann hole ich es von dort.

Comment: Warum soll *Wort, -e* unzählbar sein? Du schreibst selber *bei Worten, Worte sind*, man könnte auch *ein Wort des Dankes* dazunehmen.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Ein Wort des Dankes könnte sein: »Ich danke dir«. Das sind drei Wörter, aber es sind nicht drei Worte, sondern es ist eben **ein** Wort des Dankes. Und wenn das jemand zweimal hintereinander sagt, werden das zwar sechs Wörter, aber nicht zwei Worte, und auch nicht sechs, sondern es bleibt ein Wort des Dankes. Das ist gemeint, wenn man sagt, dass Wörter zählen kann, Worte aber nicht.

Comment: Bei unzählbarem Geld sagst du, man kann nicht *ein Geld* sagen. Aber bei angeblich unzählbarem *Wort* gibt es *ein Wort*. Und bei *Worte des Trostes* hat man den Plural von *Wort* ohne spürbare Bedeutungsveränderung, während *Geld* keinen Plural ohne Bedeutungsveränderung hat.

Comment: Der Tippfehler, den ich bereits berichtigt habe, läde zu weiteren Änderungen ein, die ich wegen Unsicherheit lieber als Kommentar nachtrage. Die Plural von *Geld* wäre *Gelder*. Mir fällt kein Beispielsatz ein; Die Suchmaschine gibt erstmal nur Wörterbücher aus. Duden definiert zweierlei, dabei Zweitens mit Plural, bpsw. *öffentliche Gelder*, das meines Erachtens gleichfalls unbestimmt bzw. wenn man so will unzählbar wirkt. Der Tippfehler deutet auch an, du wolltest vielleicht "aber es gibt kein ..." schreiben. Das regt zum Nachdenken an. Man könnte behaupten "kein *Nomen*" sei unzählbar ...

Comment: ... dabei ist die Lösung des Problems das Zählen bei Null anzufangen. ;)

Comment: @DavidVogt meinem Verständnis nach sind *Worte des Trostes* eben  *Mitleids-Bekundung-en* von mehreren Instanzen, ggf. immer das gleiche Wort. Darüber hinaus hat bspw. *im Sande versunken*, oder *vom Winde verweht* oder mir gänzlich fremd *die Türe* auch kein rein plurales *-e*. Ich merke nochmal's an, das kein Grunde besteh, *zu-m* als Verknappung zu erklären. vgl vielleicht *all'*, heute zwar *all die Worte*, aber *all Worte(e)* scheint mir vor *all help was ...* nicht ganz unwahrscheinlich. Dagegen scheint mir *in's* wegen En *into* als De \*inz gelesen fast zu gewagt. vgl *Sink into water*

Answer (score 1):

**zum** ist die  Kontraktion (Zusammenziehung) von **zu dem**.

Bei 1. heisst es somit "zu dem Abschluss bringen". Bei der Aussage "zu Wort kommen" ist "Wort" ein nicht zählbares Nomen (uncountable), deshalb hat es keinen Artikel.

Siehe auch [Wiktionary Artikel](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wort#German)

Hoffe dies hilft :)

Comment: Das Wort *zum* ist keine Abkürzung sondern eine Kontraktion (Zusammenziehung). Abkürzen sind z.B. PKW, Dipl.-Ing. u.a.

Comment: Danke, habe es angepasst

Comment: Die Erklärung ist unbefriedigend. "das Wort ergreifen" u.s.w. stützt zwar die Annahme, insoweit kein Plural erkennbar ist. Tatsächlich dürfte aber der Genus entscheidend sein, da die "Kontraktion" *zu's* irgendwie nicht zulässig ist. Vgl *zu Geld kommen*, aber *in's Geld kommen*. Von einer Kontraktion statt einer clitisch/morphemisch gebeugten Preposition zu sprechen bedürfteeiner Begründung (bzw der/des Fürworte/-s).

Comment: @vectory Wodurch unterscheidet sich das Beispiel "zu Geld kommen" zu jenem in der Frage? Geld ist auch unzählbar.
Eine Kontraktion "zus" existiert nicht, weil "zu" den Dativ verlangt (oder wie dies grammatikalisch korrekt heisst) und somit kein "das" folgen kann. Oder übersehe/vergesse ich etwas?

Comment: Ich halte die These, dass das Wort »Wort« ein unzählbares Nomen sei, für sehr gewagt. Der vorangegangene Satz enthält z.B. genau 15 Wörter, und das Zählen der Wörter fiel mir gar nicht schwer.

Comment: Die These "Wort" sei _immer_ unzählbar habe ich nicht aufgestellt. Die Antwort schränkt dies explizit auf das Beispiel ein.

Comment: @R.Hobert wenn dein Geld unzählbar ist hast du entweder Glück oder ein Problem. Mein Geld ist jedenfalls gezählt und mein zukkünftiges Einkommen allenfalls eine unbestimmte Menge.

Comment: *zu* regiert tatsächlich Dativ, entging mir in der Eile, da ich auf die Herkunft und Verwendung des Neutrums hinaus wollte. So sollte man sich fragen weshalb der bestimmte Artikel dativ neutrum *dem* lautet--doch sicherlich ersatzweise, um so mehr da *zu Wort kommen* kein eigentlicher Wem-Fall ist, der seinerseits einstmals obsolete Fälle wie Ablativ oder Vokativ(?) ersetzte. *Wozu?* kann hier nicgt mehr richtig gefragt werden, eventuell aber Eng *whereto*